# Looping through an array returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays

As you see below, I'm looping through an array of objects but the problem is that retrieve[i] is returning as undefined in the console. Why?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var retrieve = [
    {
      title: "SampleTitle-1",
      url: "SampleUrl-1"
    },
    {
      title: "SampleTitle-2",
      url: "SampleUrl-2"
    },
    {
      title: "SampleTitle-3",
      url: "SampleUrl-3"
    }
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i <= retrieve.length; i++) {
    $("ul").append("<li><a href='" + retrieve[i].url + "'>" + retrieve[i].title + "</a></li>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>



</ul>
```

Is there a syntax error I'm missing?

Sorry if the answer seems extremely obvious but I'm still learning Javascript.

Anyway, thank you for your answers and comments ahead of time :)

Comment: You're continuing the loop one time to many. Change `i <= retrieve.length` to `i < retrieve.length`.

Comment: wow xD thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

It should be  **`i < retrieve.length`** instead of **`i <= retrieve.length.`**

```
for(var i = 0; i < retrieve.length; i++) {
 $("ul").append("<li><a href='" + retrieve[i].url + "'>" +         retrieve[i].title + "</a></li>");
}
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function (){ 
   var retrieve =
   [{

    title: "SampleTitle-1",
    url: "SampleUrl-1"
   },
   {
    title: "SampleTitle-2",
    url: "SampleUrl-2"
   },
   {
    title: "SampleTitle-3",
    url: "SampleUrl-3"
   }];
   for(var i = 0; i < retrieve.length; i++) {
    $("ul").append("<li><a href='" + retrieve[i].url + "'>" +         retrieve[i].title + "</a></li>");
   }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one more iteration in the for loop than the number of elements in the array. It should be `i < retrieve.length` instead of `i <= retrieve.length`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var retrieve = [

    {

      title: "SampleTitle-1",
      url: "SampleUrl-1"

    },


    {

      title: "SampleTitle-2",
      url: "SampleUrl-2"

    },


    {

      title: "SampleTitle-3",
      url: "SampleUrl-3"

    }

  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < retrieve.length; i++) {

    $("ul").append("<li><a href='" + retrieve[i].url + "'>" + retrieve[i].title + "</a></li>");

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>



</ul>
```